# get php variable from functions php and echo it in theme template files

Tags: functions

This may seem like a silly question but I cannot figure this out.

I've created a variable in my functions.php - and I'm trying to echo it in my template files.

I'm guessing it's because of scope.

What's the simpliest what to echo a variable or create a function to allow me to output this facebook ID in various template files.

This is what I've currently got in my functions.php...

```
$fb_app_id = '68366786876786';
```

And this is how I was trying to echo it...

```
<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>
```

Any ideas would be hugely helpful, thanks you very much

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is a **programming/PHP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Comment: Use `global $your_var; echo $your_var;` or `echo $GLOBALS['your_var'];`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't have access to the value, it's likely a scope issue.  Make sure you globalize it first:

```
<?php
global $fb_app_id;
echo $fb_app_id;
?>
```

### Alternatively

I'm not a fan of global variables, so the alternative I recommend is using WordPress' built-in filter mechanism.  You add the filter in your `functions.php` file and apply it where needed.

**In `functions.php`**:

```
add_filter( 'fb_app_id', 'return_fb_app_id' );
function return_fb_app_id( $arg = '' ) {
    return '68366786876786';
}
```

**In your template files**:

```
echo apply_filters( 'fb_app_id', '' );
```

### Or use an action hook

**In `functions.php`**

```
add_action( 'fb_app_id', 'echo_fb_app_id' );
function echo_fb_app_id() {
    echo '68366786876786';
}
```

**In your template files:**

```
do_action( 'fb_app_id' );
```

Whether you use an action hook or a filter is entirely up to you.  I recommend a filter because it can *return* a value.  This is far more flexible than just injecting `echo` calls in your template.

Comment: Upvote for the filter based method. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way would be to just create a callable function, you don't really need a hook here

```
function get_fb_app_id() {
    $fb_app_id = '68366786876786';
    return $fb_app_id;
}
```

and in the template:

```
echo get_fb_app_id();
```

Comment: A wrapper function to return a global var??

Comment: no, i wouldn't set it to global, that's why i didn't add the global line.

Comment: Ok. So why isn't it inside the `function`? Currently the function would just throw an `Error: undefined (...)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Wordpress options in this case. You can set an option using either add_option() or update_option() (probably better for your case). You would use `update_option('fb_app_id', '68366786876786');` somewhere in you're functions.php file (the init hook function would probably be a good place).

You could then show this option in your theme files using `echo get_option('fb_app_id');`

The reason I would suggest this way, rather than using globals (ick) or action/filter hooks is that if you plan on releasing your theme to the public, it will be much easier to make `fb_app_id` an editable option in a theme options page.