# How to access plugin variables from theme templates without using globals?

Tags: filters, globals

Is there a way to access plugin variables from the theme template files without using globals?

I have the following situation:

- One plugin function validates POST data submitted in a form.
- If validation fails generates an WP Error
- If the WP Error is there the template should show it, otherwise it
  should be normal output.

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51145/get-php-variable-from-functions-php-and-echo-it-in-theme-template-files) there is an interesting solution using custom filters. However, I am using the same set of functions in different forms, validation rules change between form and the errors are therefore different. I would like to achieve something inline, rather than having to create different callback functions for each of the cases.

In the theme template file:

```
$errors = apply_filters('form_errors','');
if ($errors != '') {echo $errors;}
```

I would like to have something like the following in the plugin:

```
$errors = validate_form($_POST)
// the following line won't work as a callback function is needed.
// Using a callback function would probably not solve the issue, as different
// errors need to be passed depending on which form is validated. 
add_filter('form_errors', $errors);
// the following would work, but how to pass the actual errors as argument to the return_error function?
add_filter('form_errors', 'return_errors');
```

Any ideas to avoid declaring $errors as global?

Answer (score 0):

Using `add_filter` will automatically pass `$errors` to your callback function:

```
add_filter('form_errors', 'return_errors');

function return_errors($errors) {
    // validate $errors based on form conditions
    return $errors;
}
```

If the filter has more than one variable passed you can access that extra information by adding a filter priority *and* specifying the number of arguments to pass to the callback function. For example, if the validation function had:

```
return apply_filters('form_errors', $errors, $posted);
```

You could use:

```
add_filter('form_errors', 'return_errors', 10, 2);
function return_errors($errors, $posted) {
    // form validation code using $errors or $posted
    return $errors;
}
```

Note the reason you need to set the filter priority explicitly as the third argument in that case is so you can "get to" the fourth argument for `add_filter` - which again is the number of filter arguments to pass.

Comment: Thanks majick, not sure whether this solution would work in my setting. $errors is not generated in the theme template prior to calling apply_filters. Form validation is done in the plugin, if there are errors, these should be passed to the template to be displayed. Do you imply using apply_filters in the plugin function and add_filter in the theme?

Comment: If there is a specific filter from the plugin already, add a callback to that and  use it to write errors to a global variable. I know your question says "without a global", but I don't see how you would get them in the template later without re-running the form validation on $_POST all over again.